# How embedded SQL program in C gets executed as in the backend?

Tags: c, embedded-sql

When a C program is written using Embedded SQL, (eg: lets assume that a table is created with values inserted), how it gets executed in the backend before displaying the output table in the frontend?
Help is appreciated...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SQL statements are embedded into host language, say for example: C
- So, we have SQL statements and C language statements and in this
  case, SQL statements are embedded in C source code.
- Host Language code is compiled by Host compiler, Embedded language code is first preprocessed by embedded SQL preprocessor and output of preprocessor is nothing but C code, which are C-library calls, which are compiled by C compiler.

As we have directives like #include, #define for a C preprocessor, we have few directives for SQL embedded preprocessor like: `EXEC SQL begin declare section` and `EXEC SQL end declare section`

```
EXEC SQL begin declare section;
int cno;
varchar cname[31];
varchar street[31];
int zip;
char phone[13];
EXEC SQL end declare section;
```

Here, the SQL embedded preprocessor conversion is shown below:-

```
/* varchar cname[31]; */
struct {
unsigned short len;
unsigned char arr[31];
} cname;
```

This is just to give an idea of how embedded SQL works. For more detailed presentation, you may refer to [Oracle-8 Embedded SQL](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/books/Oracle8-chapter-3.pdf)